# Consolidating EF migrations into new InitialCreate

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-migrations

I have been using EF migrations for some time now and have more than 100 migration files in my project. I would like to consolidate these into a single migration before moving forward - ie I want to replace the existing InitialCreate migration with a new version that takes all my subsequent changes into account so I can then delete all the other migration files.

I do this very easily if I am not concerned with losing all the data in the DB, but I am.

How can I achieve this whilst keeping all data intact and also retaining the ability to recreate the database from scratch (without data) by just running Update-Database (which I believe is not possible using [the approach outlined by Julie Lerman](http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/using-ef-migrations-with-an-existing-database/))?

Comment: I encourage you to [submit a feature request](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/WorkItem/Create) for this. I think that "squashing" migrations is a good scenario to enable in the tooling.

Comment: if you can assume you dont need the down, could you just combine all the up proceedures?

Comment: I have the same "problem" - is there an official solution available now?

Answer (score 28):

Consider reading this nice article from Rick Strahl : 
https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/jan/13/resetting-entity-framework-migrations-to-a-clean-slate

Basically the solution is not trivial and needs more than just reseting all the migrations into one
because you have two scenarios that needs to fit in ONE migration class:

- Create a new database => the migration class should contain every table creation
- My database is already up to date => I need an empty migration class

Solution:
The idea of this process is basically this: The database and the EF schema are up to date and just the way you want it, so we are going to remove the existing migrations and create a new initial migration.

In summary, the steps to do this are:

- Remove the _MigrationHistory table from the Database
- Remove the individual migration files in your project's Migrations folder
- Enable-Migrations in Package Manager Console
- Add-migration Initial in PMC
- Comment out the code inside of the Up method in the Initial Migration
- Update-database in PMC (does nothing but creates Migration
  Entry) Remove comments in the Initial method You've now essentially
  reset the schema to the latest version.
- once the commented out migration has been executed on the desired database, uncomment the migration code

Answer (score 15):

If you're not concerned with keeping this migrations, what I've done is delete everything in your migrations folder, and then target a new database in the connection string (or pass in a new one).  After that, you can just run the add-migration command:

```
add-migration InitialCreate
```

And it should create the migration for you.

Comment: If I target a new database, I will lose all my data. Right?

Comment: It's just to create the singular migration file.. after that you can target your main DB. The reason you're doing this is so when you goto production (or move targets) there's only one migration right?

Comment: If you then target your main db, it will try and run the new consolidated migration and fail because all the tables already exist.

Comment: This is somewhat flawed approach as it will only create a migration from what EF can deduct from your code. Everything you have custom configured in previous migrations will be lost, for example custom check constraints, filtered indexes, etc.

Comment: @Pete it's flawed, yes. You can overcome it by removing `__MigrationHistory` system table. But EF *never* will preserve indexes and other stuff. You have to write it yourself, hence it's expected that you won't delete the code you wrote yourself.

Comment: I found a simpler method for above  
1.Delete the contents of the migrations folder
2.Run 'Enable-Migrations' again
3.Run 'Add-Migration'  
All done, no need to change DB name

Comment: If I had some custom sql to manage existing data, how would I manage that? Of course if I create a new migration that code will be lost.

Answer (score 3):

Below procedure has the benefit of working without doing anything with the DBs, __MigrationHistory can stay as-is. Also it will work if you have multiple different environments with different versions of the structure - provided you have the branches to match.

I turn the last migration into an initial migration. The trick is to use the oldest version of the code and DB that is in use, replace its last migration with a new initial migration and delete all previous migrations. Newer branches keep the more recent migrations so those will still work after merging to older branches.

So start in the OLDEST branch - PROD, normally - and do:

1. Remove all but the last migration
2. Remove the migration code in both the "Up" and "Down" methods in the last migration
3. Change build action of the last migration to "None" to let EF ignore it
4. Change active connection to point to a local DB database.
5. Make sure this local DB database does not exist
6. add-migration Initial
7. Copy Up and Down code from the created "Initial" migration to the last migration
8. Delete Initial migration
9. Change build action of the last migration back to "Compile"
10. Check in
11. Merge changes up
12. Test in DEV branch on LocalDB DB - it should do the new initial migration as well as the subsequent ones with no issues
13. Test in main branch on the latest DB - it shouldn't do anything

Note above only works if you don't add stuff to the migrations that EF doesn't do itself. E.g. if you add DB views etc. than the newly created migration won't get those, it only gets the scripts EF generates based on your code.

Comment: This is a particularly elegant solution. For EF core 7 on PgSQL you can add `3a. Change build action for the Designer` and `3b. Exclude Snapshot file from project`, `7a.Copy the contents of the designer file` `8a. Add the snapshot back`

Answer (score 1):

Removing all migrations or regenerating them has drawbacks so we took an approach we merged all older migrations.

It require a bit of scripting. You read about the details here https://www.bokio.se/engineering-blog/how-to-squash-ef-core-migrations/ and see the scripts here https://github.com/bokio/EFCoreTools/tree/main/MigrationSquasher

The basic is the following steps though (copied from the blog post):

**Overview of our approach**

1. Create a new fresh database from the old migrations (We will use
   this for comparison later)
2. Find a suitable target migration to be
   the new initial (We picked one about 3 months old)
3. Write a script to
   merge the Up() methods of all earlier migrations into the Up()
   method of a new migration. We ignored Down() because we don't use it
   for old migrations.
4. Generate this migration and add it to the
   project. In our case we called it
   20200730130157_SquashedMigrations1.cs. We used the snapshot from the
   target migration we had picked.
5. Generate a 2nd prep migration that
   inserts into the migrations history that
   20200730130157_SquashedMigrations1.cs has already run. We called
   this 20200730130156_SquashedMigrations1_prep.cs. Note the slightly
   smaller timestamp on that one to make sure it runs before the real
   migrations.
6. Delete the old migrations
7. Point our config to a new
   database and run the migrations.
8. Compare that the schema we generate
   is equal using the Sql Schema Compare in Visual Studio.
9. Work through
   the issues until we have equal schemas. This part is a bit
   complicated but I will get back to it.
10. Merge and  (Ok, we did run
    more tests both on local and staging databases)

I hope this helps someone else. The EF team is looking at improving this story so if you have feedback on your requirements it probably help them to post that now https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/2174.

Answer (score 1):

We had the same problem.
The general solution we found was to

- Archive the old migration / context on a Nuget Package (including dependancies and with a different namespace to avoid conflicts)
- Delete all migrations and create a new Init (InitV2) Migration from scratch.
- Change the startup sequence of our application:

  - If the database contains the first old Init migration then

    - Migrate the database using the Nuget Package to be sure it will be up to date
    - Then erase the content of the __EFMigrationHistory table and Insert the new migration in the table
  - After that use the standard Migrate method on the new context
- That's it !

This solution is relatively simple. It solve all cases

- New database (will be using the InitV2)
- Old Database (will be upgrading to the last V1 Migration and after that to the last version of the v2 Database)

*Be aware, if you used custom scripts/sql(...) in the v1 migrations, you have to check if the v2 Init migrations needs it.*

To be sure it was OK, we created an empty database from v1 migrations and another one from v2 init migration and did a schema and data diff (with Visual Studio SQL Server Tools)