# How to drop table from entity framework context?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-6, azure-sql-database, entity-framework-migrations

I have a table in Sql Azure that I need to drop and recreate. I've made a lot of changes to the table over many migrations so I thought the easiest way to do this would be to drop the table in a manual migration file, then have the auto-migration recreate the table again. However, when I create my own migration with

```
Add-Migration [MigrationName] -IgnoreChanges
```

and drop the tables the automatic-migration doesn't pick it up so it doesn't know to recreate the tables. I think this has something to do with the entity framework context not knowing that I actually dropped a table.

So basically I would like to create a migration that drops a table and recreates it and I would like for the recreate code to be created automatically by automatic migrations. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: If your goal is to consolidate migrations, you can just delete the old ones and create a new one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13379519/consolidating-ef-migrations-into-new-initialcreate

Comment: @WiteCastle Did you tried excluding the entity, adding a migration and then including it again? Are you using automatic-migrations on a production environment?

Comment: @AugustoBarreto How would I do that? I tried to do it excluding the Model file but then I'd have to go through the entire code and comment out the references to the model. What's the easiest way to try that? Also, we're still in development so I haven't tried this in a production environment.

Comment: @WiteCastle You are right. It depends on where you migrations are located. If they are in the main web project it will be difficult. If you have your migrations on a class library you could unload all other projects. I think maybe you could try adding the [NotMapped] attribute over your entity instead of excluding it. I'm currently working on a similar scenario as yours. We have a Web Site and a Azure Sql Db, and we are using automatic migrations. When we made too much changes to the model, I delete the db and restart the app to create it again. We'll use explicit migrations after the launch

Comment: @WiteCastle Locally, we use the DropCreateIfModelChanges initializer. We don't use it on Azure because it gave me too many problems and I don't know why.